# Updating the Home category content is not displayed

Tags: shopware6

My store is in the default English plus Swedish. Only Swedish is the "active" language - no dropdown on the front for selecting language.

But, if I do changes in the content for the top category ("Home", Swedish language) these changes are not displays on the home page.

So, selecting "Catalogues" > "Categories" and then the Home category. Selecting the Swedish language and the Layout tab. No matter what I change here (text or images) are reflected on the home page.

To be able to change the home page, I had to created a new Shopping Experience template (landing page), and do the changes there (in the Swedish language).

Why is it so? Should I not be able to change the content on the home page using "Categories"? I *think* that worked before...